# How to say 'working late' for a salaried job

Tags: english-to-japanese

If you work at a salaried job and you want to say "I'm working late today"

Can you say

> 今日、遅く働いています

> 今日、残業しています

or do you say it another way?

Comment: I'm curious about 遅く働いています.  To me (non-native speaker) it sounds like you started work late in the day.  If you wanted to say you worked late perhaps 遅くまで働いています.  But, I lack the confidence on this matter to assert an answer.

Comment: I wasn't sure if 遅く can only mean late as in 'starting late' or if it can also mean late as in 'ending late'/'continuing until it's late'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what you mean by "late".

[残業]{ざん・ぎょう} means "overtime work".  So it could mean working late, but not necessarily (like if you were working a weekend shift or something).

And if it is for a normal shift, it could mean "later than normal", but not necessarily late into the night.  So if you normally work, say, 6:00-15:00, but today you are 残業ing until 18:00, well that's late compared to your normal quitting time, but I don't think anyone would consider 18:00 "late" in the day/evening.